# WP_Query to get most views in last month

Tags: wordpress

i want to get those post with the most views in the last 30 days with a WP_Query.

I tried this:

```
$popularpost = new WP_Query( 
array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC'),
));
```

but there is no time range in it. if i add the `date_query` option, it shows only those posts, which were published in this period, but i want the views of this period.

```
'date_query' => array(
    'after' => date('Ymd', strtotime("-30 days"))
)
```

is there an option to get the most viewed posts in a period without an additional plugin?

Comment: this is not a native feature in wordpress, I guess you used [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/) code, and it doesn't keep track of time

Comment: yes, but only the `WP_Query` part. so isn't there a solution? maybe with jetpack statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was thinking how to do this and I thought of a solution. I started writing it down a little to better understand the process and in the end I wrote all the code. :)

It's not fully tested yet, and it can definitely be improved, but it's a start to understand the logic. So here it is:

---

### Most seen posts in last 30 days

I copied part of [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/) that saves a counter of the post views as postmeta. Needing to keep track of time, I added an array as postmeta that will contain the post views for each day of the last month.

```
// detect post views count and store it as a custom field for each post
function so29460362_set_post_views( $postID ) {
    $days  = get_post_meta($postID, 'so29460362_post_views_count_days', true);
    $today = date('Ymd');
    // update today's counter
    $days[$today] = isset($days[$today]) ? $days[$today]+1 : 1;
    update_post_meta($postID, 'so29460362_post_views_count_days', $days);
    update_post_meta($postID, 'so29460362_post_views_count', array_sum($days));
}
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

The previous function is called everytime a single post is loaded:

```
function so29460362_track_post_views ( $post_id ) {
    if ( !is_singular( 'post' ) ) return;
    if ( empty($post_id) )
        $post_id = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
    so29460362_set_post_views($post_id);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so29460362_track_post_views');
```

Ok so until now it saves a different views counter for each post every day, but we need only the last 30 days, so here's the trick: once a day we're gonna delete all the counters older than 30 days.

We can do that by setting up a daily scheduled event:

```
// schedule cleanup old days data
add_action('init', 'so29460362_schedule_daily_cleanup');

function so29460362_schedule_daily_cleanup(){
    //check if event scheduled before
    if(!wp_next_scheduled('so29460362_daily_cleanup_cronjob'))
        //shedule event to run after every day
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'so29460362_daily_cleanup_cronjob');
}
```

And now we can add the cleaning function to that cron job event:

```
add_action('so29460362_daily_cleanup_cronjob', 'so29460362_daily_cleanup');

function so29460362_daily_cleanup(){
    // get all published posts ids
    $posts = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'fields' => 'ids') );
    // date 30 days ago
    $clean_from_date = date('Ymd', strtotime('-30 days'));
    // for every post delete old counters
    foreach ($posts->posts as $postID) {
        $days = get_post_meta($postID, 'so29460362_post_views_count_days', true);
        if(!empty($days)) {
            foreach($days as $date => $views)
                if($date < $clean_from_date)
                    unset($days[$date]);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'so29460362_post_views_count_days', $days);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'so29460362_post_views_count', array_sum($days));
        }
    }
}
```

---

That's it. Now we can get the most seen posts with this query:

```
$popularposts = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'so29460362_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
) );
```

As I said it needs to be fully tested, so if you find an error please let me know.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks a lot